# How to access custom property created in App.xaml.cs in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have created my own custom property in app.xaml.cs file
I require to access this property in one of my viewmodel.
When i try to access via Application object it does not show up.
Can anyone help me with this.

Regards

Answer (score 16):

Use `Application.Current` to access custom property you have crated.

```
var currentApp =  Application.Current as App;
currentApp.YourPropertyName = "WhateverYouWant";
```

Read this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) with example on how to do it.

Comment: This might be because I'm new to C#... but note that `if ((App)App.Current).YourPropertyName) {}` doesn't work!  It must be a direct cast with `as`.

Comment: Or ``((App)Application.Current).YourPropertyName`` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or simply `Application.Current.Properties["YourSavePropertyKey"]`